# Trouble creating real NTFS links using Cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, ntfs, cygwin, symbolic-link

I have administrator privileges and would like Cygwin's `ln -s` to make NTFS links instead of the fake `!<symlink>` files that only Cygwin understands.

I tried the following, based on [Cygwin documentation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-symlinks):

- set my CYGWIN environment variable to `winsymlinks:native` in my `.bashrc` file
- ran the shell as an Administrator (required for use of `mklink`)

Yet whenever I try `ln -s //networkdrive/directory.65`, Cygwin actually creates a "symlink file" instead of an NTFS junction. In the file browser, I can't enter the directory "directory.65" because Windows does not see it as a directory, but instead a "65" file.

Am I actually running it as an Administrator? I set the "Run as administrator" seting for the Desktop shortcut and the executables, `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe` and `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe`.

Note: `uname` shows that I am using Cygwin 1.7.18.

**edit:** Using `cmd.exe` and issuing `mklink /D directory.65 \\networkdrive\directory.65` indeed made a real NTFS link. The problem is just getting Cygwin's `ln -s` to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my CYGWIN environment variable from

```
export CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native
```

to

```
export CYGWIN=winsymlinks
```

The former is in the *current* documentation, but that format is apparently not supported in Cygwin 1.7, even though 1.7 does support native NTFS links.

Switching to the older format solved the issue.